# Multi line text in LitRenderer in vaadin grid

Tags: vaadin

Does anyone maybe have an example of a LitRenderer with multiple lines of potentially wrapped text in a vaadin grid please?

All the examples in the documentation just have a bold line and a small single line of text underneath. I have tried to create a bold line and then a multi line text paragraph underneath it, but I cant get the grid to render this properly.

The text should ideally change width responsively with flex grow, wrap accordlingly and potentially truncate if no space is available.

Edit:

I think I got this working as follows:

```
    grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<SubProductTypeOption>of("""
                <vaadin-vertical-layout style="line-height: var(--lumo-line-height-m); height: 175px; cursor: pointer;">
                    <span> [[item.name]] </span>
                    <span style="font-size: var(--lumo-font-size-s); color: var(--lumo-secondary-text-color); white-space:normal;">[[item.description]]</span>
                </vaadin-vertical-layout>
            """)
            .withProperty("name", SubProductTypeOption::getName)
            .withProperty("description", SubProductTypeOption::getDescription)
    ).setFlexGrow(1);
```

Seems to work so far...

Comment: You could add an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Your question/headline is about a `LitRenderer`, but your "got this working"-example is a `TemplateRenderer`. If you still want a `LitRenderer`, you have to exchange `TemplateRenderer` by `LitRenderer` and `[[item.name]]` by `${item.name}`. Multiline you can do with a template like this: `<div><b>${item.a}</b><br/>${item.b}<br/>${item.c}</div>` (template used in a `VirtualList` in Vaadin 23).

Comment: I abandoned the LitRenderer as I couldn't get it to work. I also tried using html <br>'s but this never wrapped long lines of text properly - short lines of text work fine but anything longer just messed with the layout and smeared over cell borders. In my example the "description" could be 5 to 10 lines worth of text. Perhaps it it now fixed? The Vaadin example for VirtualList at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/virtual-list unfortunately doesn't have any examples of wrapped text.